# Secure connection using bonjour

Tags: ios, macos, ssl, certificate, bonjour

I am about to develop a application that should be able to connect my mac (osx) to my iPhone (ios) and I am thinking of using bonjour over wifi. The application will be used to access keys on my phones so security is vital.

I am wondering if bonjour can use any secure encryption like SSL or if any other security is implemented by default so that is "secure enough"?

Answer (score 1):

Bonjour is just for discovery, you can publish SSL services or whatever network services you want.
You don't use bonjour to transmit data anyway.